# PHP strange comparison behavior

Tags: php

Why php consider empty array greater than one? And object not?
And if compared to boolean even strange.

```
var_dump(array() > 1); // Print true
var_dump(array() === false); // Print false
var_dump(array() === true); // Print false again
```

and

```
var_dump(new stdClass > 1); // Print false
```

and

```
var_dump('' > 1); // Print false
```

PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u7

Comment: It's quite obvious why var_dump(array() === false); and var_dump(array() === true); prints false, as an array is not a boolean and the === operator checks, if both are the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array() > 1
```

Is not really a meaningful comparison, although admittedly `array() < 1` being true seems more intuitive. However from the docs an array is always greater when compared with a non array.

```
array() === false
array() === true
```

`===` checks that the compared items are the same type. An array is not the same type as a boolean so both the above are false.

```
'' > 1
```

The empty string is 0 in the above so this is false.

```
new stdClass > 1
```

This gives a notice of `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int` which is likely why you're seeing false.

[More info here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Ok I got it! But Im looking for "why" in C implementation. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php:

> array is always greater